# Trying to open up a set of programs and set them to a specific location upon bootup, Chrome logins + Windows 11

Tags: google-chrome, windows-11

I have a use case where I would like to open up 8 different Chrome browser windows (each one a different user) on a secondary 4k monitor, in a very specific resolution so that they're tiled and I can see stuff in it.

Right now I use Microsoft PowerToys' FancyZones to snap everything to exact position, so life is mostly fine except for the daily "open up all the browsers and snap them to the grids" chore I do at the beginning of the day.  Do people have any recommendations for how to simplify this even more?

I'm also open to some sort of macros program to record my mouse actions and run at startup if there isn't a programmatic way to "open  at windows location <X,Y>" too, though that seems to be a bit clunkier of a solution.  (But clunky is still better than manual!)

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do it with Autoit scripting language. You should be able to move/size any window based on it's title. (assuming they all have different titles)